# Junit testing Expected exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException, junit.framework.assertionFailedError

Tags: java, exception, junit, assertions

I have some problems getting my JUnit tests to work. I want to test the method if it finds the files or if it doesn't and if it catches it, but I'm not getting the expected results. My filenames are studenter, results and uppgift. Here are the tests I've formatted.

```
@Test(expected = java.io.FileNotFoundException.class)
public void testGradeAndPrintFileEX() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("gradeAndPrintFile");
    String assignmentFile = "uppgsift";
    String studentFile = "studentder";
    String resultFile = "resuslts";

    Grader instance = new Grader();

    instance.gradeAndPrintFile(assignmentFile, studentFile, resultFile);                
}

@Test(expected = java.io.IOException.class)
public void testGradeAndPrintFileEX2() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("gradeAndPrintFile");
    String assignmentFile = "uppgift";
    String studentFile = "studenter";
    String resultFile = "results";
    Grader instance = new Grader();

    instance.gradeAndPrintFile(assignmentFile, studentFile, resultFile);        
}
```

and here is my class:

```
    @Override
    public void gradeAndPrintFile(String assignmentFile, String studentFile, String resultFile) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        student = new Student();

//throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        try {
            FileWriter file = new FileWriter(resultFile);
            BufferedReader studentReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(studentFile));
            BufferedReader assignmentReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(assignmentFile)));

            String assagning;
            Map<String, Integer> hashMap = new HashMap<>();

            while ((assagning = assignmentReader.readLine()) != null) {

                String[] cut = assagning.split(";");
                hashMap.put(cut[0], Integer.parseInt(cut[1]));
            }

            assignment = new Assignment();
            assignment.setLevelForPass(hashMap.get("G"));
            assignment.setLevelForPassWithDistinction(hashMap.get("VG"));

            String studenter;
            String[] studentArray;

            while ((studenter = studentReader.readLine()) != null) {

                studentArray = studenter.split(";");

                eMail = studentArray[2];
                lastName = studentArray[0];
                firstName = studentArray[1];

                student.setEmail(eMail);
                student.setLastName(lastName);
                student.setFirstName(firstName);

                ArrayList<Integer> poangLista = new ArrayList<>();

                for (int i = 0; i < studentArray.length; i++) {
                    if (i > 2) {

                        String numbers = studentArray[i];

                        poangLista.add(Integer.parseInt(numbers));

                    }
                }

                grade = new Grade();
                grade.setUp(student, poangLista, assignment);
                System.out.println(grade.toString());

                file.write(grade.toString() + "\n");
                file.flush();

            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Grader.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Grader.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

the error im getting is a bunch of red rows witch i have no idea what they mean, they are as follows:

```
feb 15, 2015 9:05:19 EM grader.Grader gradeAndPrintFile
ALLVARLIG: null
java.io.FileNotFoundException: studentder (Det går inte att hitta filen)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:131)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:87)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:58)
    at grader.Grader.gradeAndPrintFile(Grader.java:47)
    at grader.GraderTest.testGradeAndPrintFileEX(GraderTest.java:69)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.ExpectException.evaluate(ExpectException.java:22)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:30)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:30)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at junit.framework.JUnit4TestAdapter.run(JUnit4TestAdapter.java:39)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.run(JUnitTestRunner.java:532)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.launch(JUnitTestRunner.java:1179)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.main(JUnitTestRunner.java:1030)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test will never pass, because you are catching the `IOException` and not rethrowing it further:

```
catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Grader.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    throw ex; // add this line
}
```

**You should rethrow the exception**.

You could remove the catching of `FileNotFoundException` as it extends `IOException` and so both can be handled by a single block as I proposed.

Comment: aha ok, i think i understand but i still got the same error, however, added another throw ex after FileNotFound and got EX through but not EX2

  `} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Grader.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        throw ex;
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Grader.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        throw ex;
        }
            
    }

}`

Comment: im sorry not realy sure how to format the code to look as pretty as yourse

Comment: I also noticed that a file named resuslts (as in the test EX2, not result) also gets created in projectfolder as in the test EX2

Comment: Ouh well i still get failed exception on EX2 (same as before) after i added the second throw. also noticed that my result file is marked blue in netbeans (unrecognized file, locally modified) could that have something to do with it?

Comment: hey actualy got it to work now, i had the wrong name on some files (silly me!) but thank you for youre help, wouldnt have figured that out by my self!